# Since plugging in a screen using DVI, speakers in green socket now "not plugged in"

Tags: windows-7, audio

I run a set of RCA/phonos from the green socket in the mainboard to my hi fi. All was fine until I unplugged the monitor and plugged it back in. It is and has always been DVI.

Now Windows 7 thinks it has a HDMI connection and wants to send sound to the "TV". Worse, it doesn't detect that I have plugged in speakers - or headphones in the front.

In 'Sound' on Playback tab, I have:

```
Speakers
High Definition Audio Device
Not plugged in

Digital Audio (HDMI)
High Definition Audio Device
Default Device [with a tick and level meter]
```

I rolled back with System Restore but its just the same!

Thanks!

Edit 1 - Microphone not detected; wondering if the sound chip has gone pop!?

Edit 2 - With VGA it doesn't work either. I think its defaulting to the video card's sound device (HDMI) because its not detecting any speakers, and I wonder simply if something is faulty, that it blew when I messed around with the hi-fi and phonos.

Comment: What kind of video card is this? I'm also wondering if you could just disable the HDMI sound device entries in the device manager to stop the conflict with the on-board (ive also seen on-board audio get turned off automatically in the BIOS setup and once the HDMI are disabled in windows you have to reboot and turn the on-board back on to get it to work again).

Comment: Its a GT 430, the 3D range for HTPCs

Answer (score 0):

Well, I opened the tin and worked out it has a M4A78LT-M LE mainboard and downloaded the sound driver for it (some VIA board).

This worked?! Odd. Really odd.